# Cryptography in metro app

Tags: c#, cryptography, microsoft-metro

I would like to use Pbkdf2 in my app. I do not need anything complex.

I have piece of code:

```
  string passwordSalt = "salt";
  string password = "pass";

  Byte[] passwordSaltBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwordSalt);
  Byte[] passwordBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

  var deriveKey = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBuffer,
                                         passwordSaltBuffer, 10000);
```

Obviously I can't use it in metro app.

How it's going to look like equivalent code in metro style app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample for `PBKDF2_MD5` -

```
KeyDerivationParameters params = KeyDerivationParameters.BuildForPbkdf2(
                                  passwordBuffer,   // Salt
                                  10000);           // PBKDF2 Iteration Count

KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("PBKDF2_MD5")
                                 .CreateKey(passwordBuffer);

IBuffer derived = CryptographicEngine.DeriveKeyMaterial(key, params, 64);
```

For more details how for Cryptography sample in WinRT refer sample from MSDN - [CryptoWinRT sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CryptoWinRT-sample-0d74f26b).